# Can't run my register form - "A page can only contain a form tag on one server side"

Tags: asp.net, web, master-pages

### **Master Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html dir ="rtl">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div id="menu">
                <center>
                <table border="1" style="border-color:black">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="height:39px">
                            <a href="Register.aspx">Sign up</a>
                            <a href="Login1.aspx">Sign in</a>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </center>
            </div>


            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### **Register**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <title>טופס רישום</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet1.css" /><style type="text/css">
        .auto-style4 {
            width: 27px;
        }
        </style><script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript" dir="rtl">                    
                    function checkForm() {
                        var allCheck = true;
                        if (!checkUserName()) allCheck = false;
                        if (!checkPassword()) allCheck = false;
                        if (!checkValidPassword()) allCheck = false;
                        if (!checkEmail()) allCheck = false;
                        if (!checkPhone()) allCheck = false;

                        return allCheck;
                    }
                    function checkUserName() {
                        var flag = true;
                        var n = document.getElementById("username").value;
                        if (n == "") {
                            document.getElementById("mUsername").value = "חובה שם משתמש!";
                            document.getElementById("mUsername").style.display = "inline";
                            flag = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            document.getElementById("mUsername").style.display = "none";
                            if (n.length >= 1 && n.length < 5) {
                                document.getElementById("mUsername").value = "שם משתמש קצר מדי, 4 תווים לפחות!";
                                document.getElementById("mUsername").style.display = "inline";
                                flag = false;
                            }
                            else {
                                document.getElementById("mUsername").style.display = "none";
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    function checkPassword() {
                        var flag = true;
                        var n = document.getElementById("mPass").value;
                        if (n == "") {
                            document.getElementById("mPass").value = "חובה להכניס סיסמה!";
                            document.getElementById("mPass").style.display = "inline";
                            flag = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            document.getElementById("mPass").style.display = "none";
                            if (n.length >= 1 && n.length < 6) {
                                document.getElementById("mPass").value = "סיסמה קצרה מדי, 6 תווים לפחות!";
                                document.getElementById("mPass").style.display = "inline";
                                flag = false;
                            }
                            else {
                                document.getElementById("mPass").style.display = "none";
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    function checkValidPassword() {
                        var flag = true;
                        var n1 = document.getElementById("pass").value;
                        var n2 = document.getElementById("passCheck").value;
                        if (n1 != n2) {
                            document.getElementById("mPassCheck").value = "הסיסמאות אינן תואמות!"
                            document.getElementById("mPassCheck").style.display = "inline";
                        }
                        else {
                            if (n2 == "") {
                                document.getElementById("mPassCheck").value = "יש לאמת סיסמאות!";
                                document.getElementById("mPassCheck").style.display = "inline";
                                flag = false;

                            }
                        }



                    }
                    function checkEmail() {
                        var flag = true;
                        var e = document.getElementById("email").value;
                        if ((e.indexOf('@') < 2) || e.lastIndex('.') < e.indexOf('@')) 
                            {
                            document.getElementById("mEmail").value = "!כתובת מייל אינה נכונה";
                            document.getElementById("mEmail").style.display = "inline";
                        }
                        else {
                            document.getElementById("mMail").style.display = "none"
                            var status = false;
                            for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
                                if (e.charAt(i) == " ") status = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (status == true)
                        {
                            document.getElementById("mMail").value = "!כתובת אימייל אינה נכונה";
                            document.getElementById("mMail").style.display = "inline";
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                    function checkPhone() {
                        var flag = true;
                        var p = document.getElementById("number").value;


                    }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <form id="regist" runat="server" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
           <div id="דף הרשמה">
           <center>
            <table class="blueTable">


                <thead>
                <tr class="table.blueTable tr:nth-child(even)">
                    <th colspan="2" class="table.blueTable th">טופס רישום</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr class="">
                    <td class="table.blueTable td"><b>:שם פרטי</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" size="15" class="defaultTextBox" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>שם משפחה</b>:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="familyname" name="familyname" class="defaultTextBox" size="15" /></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td><b>שם משתמש</b>:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="defaultTextBox" size="10" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mUsername" id="mUsername" style="display:none;
 background-color:Black; color:azure; font-weight: bold;" disabled="disabled" class="defaultTextBox" size="25" /></td>
                     <td></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td><b>תאריך לידה:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="birthyear" name="birthyear" size="4" value="הזן שנה" />
                        <select name="month" id="month" class="select">
                           <option value="0" selected="selected" >בחר חודש</option>
                           <option value="1">ינואר</option>
                           <option value="2">פברואר</option>
                           <option value="3">מרץ</option>
                           <option value="4">אפריל</option>
                           <option value="5">מאי</option>
                           <option value="6">יוני</option>
                           <option value="7">יולי</option>
                           <option value="8">אוגוסט</option>
                           <option value="9">ספטמבר</option>
                           <option value="10">אוקטובר</option>
                           <option value="11">נובמבר</option>
                           <option value="12">דצמבר</option>
                        </select> 
                        <select name="days" id="days">
                           <option value="d" selected="selected" >בחר יום</option>
                           <option value="1">1</option>
                           <option value="2">2</option>
                           <option value="3">3</option>
                           <option value="4">4</option>
                           <option value="5">5</option>
                           <option value="6">6</option>
                           <option value="7">7</option>
                           <option value="8">8</option>
                           <option value="9">9</option>
                           <option value="10">10</option>
                           <option value="11">11</option>
                           <option value="12">12</option>
                           <option value="13">13</option>
                           <option value="14">14</option>
                           <option value="15">15</option>
                           <option value="16">16</option>
                           <option value="17">17</option>
                           <option value="18">18</option>
                           <option value="19">19</option>
                           <option value="20">20</option>
                           <option value="21">21</option>
                           <option value="22">22</option>
                           <option value="23">23</option>
                           <option value="24">24</option>
                           <option value="25">25</option>
                           <option value="26">26</option>
                           <option value="27">27</option>
                           <option value="28">28</option>
                           <option value="29">29</option>
                           <option value="30">30</option>
                           <option value="31">31</option> 
                            </select>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>סיסמה:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" size="10" class="defaultTextBox" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mPass" id="mPass" style="display:none;
 background-color:Black; color:azure; font-weight: bold;" disabled="disabled" class="defaultTextBox" size="25" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>אימות סיסמה:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="password" id="passCheck" name="passCheck" size="10" class="defaultTextBox" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mPassCheck" id="mPassCheck" style="display:none;
 background-color:Black; color:azure; font-weight: bold;" disabled="disabled" class="defaultTextBox" size="25" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>אימייל:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="30" class="defaultTextBox" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mEmail" id="mEmail" style="display:none;
 background-color:Black; color:azure; font-weight: bold;" disabled="disabled" class="defaultTextBox" size="25" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>מספר טלפון:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="number" id="number" name="number" size="7" />
                        <select name="kidomet" id="kidomet">
                           <option value="k" selected="selected" >קידומת</option>
                           <option value="2">052</option>
                           <option value="8">058</option>
                           <option value="4">054</option>
                           <option value="0">050</option>
                       </select> 
                    </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>גובה:</td>
                     <td><input type="number" id="height" name="height" size="3" class="defaultTextBox" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>מין:</b></td>
                    <td><select name="profession" id="profession">
                           <option value="g" selected="selected" >בחר מין</option>
                           <option value="m">זכר</option>
                           <option value="f">נקבה</option>
                           <option value="o">אחר</option>
                       </select> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>הערות:</b></td>
                    <td><textarea cols="15" rows="10" name="notes" id="notes" class="advancedSearchTextbox">הערות:</textarea></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <center>
                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<input type="submit" value="שלח" id="submit" name="submit"/> &nbsp &nbsp
                    <input type="reset" value="נקה" id="clean" name="submit"/></td>
                    </center>
                </tr>

            </table>
           </center>
        </div>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

I'm using a master page and when I'm trying to run the code I'm getting the following error:

> A page can have only one server-side form tag.

I have a form tag and server side code in both the register and the master pages. I couldn't figure it out, what I have to do to solve this error?

Comment: Well, what do you think the error message means? It seems pretty clear to me. Remove the <form> from The Register Page.

Answer (score 0):

Like **@VDWWD** pointed at comment section, as the error says that a page can only contains one server-sige form tag. So you need to  remove this `form` from page:

```
<form id="regist" runat="server" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
```